# MAC OS X: ALT+Left Click move window possible in 10.5 and up

Tags: macos, mac

Is this possible in Mac OS 10.5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default, but with [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/), you can do the same thing, just a different shortcut. With Afloat, you use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+Drag.

Comment: this doesn't work in all apps thoough. Solves most of my problems though.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, too low of a rep to post a comment for clarification, so I'll have to do it in this.

Can you clarify what you mean? For instance, one could interpret your question and say it's been possible to move windows by a left-click and drag on the window's title bar since well before OS X 10.0. In other words, why in the world would you want to use Alt (Option)? (Or what difference would that make?)

Or, are you referring to being able to, from the app you're currently in, move or resize the window of an application that is in the background without making that application active? If so, you can do that by holding down the Command key and dragging the window to move it, resize it, etc. That has been around since at least 10.2. You can also use this method within the same application to move and resize a window without bringing that window forward.

(You can also hold down the Command key and click on buttons or controls in a window that's in the background (even in a different app) and have that click be performed in the corresponding application without that application being brought to the front).

Comment: I think what the asker means is to be able to move a window from anywhere on the window by holding down a key combination and drag it. Much like you can on most Linux window managers: Hold down Alt and drag the window from anywhere on that window to move it.

Comment: Mr. Man you're correct. This is exactly what I would like to do. It screams 1337. And mac definitely. Sadly the os seems to me its becoming counter-intuitive.

Comment: This is why Linux rocks it is the most intuiitive OS of all out of the box. But when my manager tries to e.g. operate sth beautiful and simple like Libre Impress he cannot think simple enough to operate this beautiful piece of software. People are thinking in terms of complicated, useless, counterintuutive Microsoft patterns. They have unlearned the simple. Happy I made the switch to Linux in 2002. Never looked back ever since. Ever (even when working at Microsoft)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.de/) für this task. You can customize the Shortcut as you desire e.g. ⌥+Click.
[image]

In Addition there are other nice things that HyperDock can do:

- Preview and select windows & tabs by moving the mouse on a dock item.
- Use shortcuts to open new windows and documents with click.
- Window Snapping

Just check out the Trial and if it meets your requirements, $9.95 USD isn’t that much.

Comment: Select this as answer. Downvote the others, waste of time.

Comment: This is nice and it works but there's some serious lag vs normal moving/resizing

Answer (score 2):

Afloat has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/millenomi/afloat
It seems to still work with OS X 10.8, though no development has undergone since 2 years...

[Edit: sept 2017] An even better solution is mySIMBL (https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL), a package manager to install and load many SIMBL plugins, including Afloat.